# Alternative for Timestamp attribute days (which seems to be deprecated)?

Tags: pandas, timestamp, time-series

```
daily['annual'] = (daily.index - daily.index[0].days / 356.

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'days'
```

The attribute days seems to be deprecated. I want to build a counter that increases from day 1, and measures how many years have passed.

I tried to use the attribute dayofyear. But then I received the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'float'
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you aim to achieve here?

Comment: Check my description and https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.06-Linear-Regression.ipynb Input [21]

Comment: you made a mistake with the brackets. It is `(daily.index - daily.index[0]).days / 365` (furthermore it is `365`, not `356`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake with the brackets, and the number of days in a year is near `365`, not `356` (although that is still not entirely correct). You thus should write:

```
daily['annual'] = (daily.index - daily.index[0]).days / 365
```